# How to use base css file using twig

Tags: css, symfony

I have one base .css file under `app/Resources/public/css/`. Every file should include it so I wanna place it in the layout file. I also want to include additional css files if there'd be any. This is how my layout looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" media="all" href="{{ asset('css/base.css') }}">
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

As far as I know it should include my base .css file and any other .css files I use in stylesheet block.

However it doesn't work. It generates the relative url to the css file, but it just doesn't open. Typing this url to the browser (`localhost/project/web/css/base.css`) gives some uncaught exception.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFitnessManager\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php:33 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFitnessManager\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1207): appProdUrlMatcher->match('/css/base.css') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFitnessManager\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1872): Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->match('/css/base.css') #2 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFitnessManager\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1667): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFitnessManager\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1600): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFitnessManager\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1764): Symfony\Comp in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFitnessManager\app\cache\prod\classes.php on line 1883
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your primary layout that you're extending is in `app/Resources/views` you can use something like this:

```
{% stylesheets
    '../app/Resources/public/css/base.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: I tried that but it shows An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_17022fb_0" as such route does not exist.") in "CoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig"

Comment: Post the view code for `CoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig` or is that the view above in your post?

Comment: {% extends "::base.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
Hello world!
{% endblock %}

Comment: That's it. It works perfectly when I delete the whole stylesheets tag.

Comment: is your `base.html.twig` located in `app/Resources/views` or is it in `CoreBundle/Resources/views`?

Comment: app/Resources/views, just like it was by default.

Comment: Ok, based on what you said everything should be working.  This is the exact structure I use in most of my apps. Try doing a manual cache clear eg `rm -rf app/cache/*`